# Php7.4 preload with opcache enabled fpm error

Tags: nginx, fpm, opcache, symfony5, php-7.4

I'm currently using `nginx`, `php7.4-fpm` (php7.4.2) and symfony5.

I tried to enable php7.4 preload feature I'm getting fpm error.

`*1 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client`

php.ini:
`opcache.preload=/var/www/domain/var/cache/prod/App_KernelProdContainer.preload.php`
`opcache.preload_user=ubuntu`

Any suggestions what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue with php7.4.2, symfony 5 and nginx and after some research, here what I found:

- https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/34910#issuecomment-578761190
- https://ezplatform.com/blog/php-7.4-opcache-preloading-benchmark

It seems to be a bug with opcache.preload_user parameter which is mandatory :)

I suggest you to comment opcache.preload and opcache.preload_user and wait for php7.4.3.

Hope it helps

Comment: php 8.1 still have this issue